# Проблемы с добавлением английского текста в бд

Tags: php

Сайт должен работать на запад и там все на Английском. Проблема вот в чем. В английском есть предложение в которых встречается верхняя запитая. пример Sarmitcare.com has a payment method that works for you, with **VeriSign's** world renowned secure payment technology keeping your information safe at all times.

скрипт выдает ошибку `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a wide variety of payment options, Sarmitcare.com offers convenience to customer' at line 1`

как можно от этого избавится????

Comment: От верхней запИтой можно избавится с помощью mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: но вот если она нужна в тексте?

Comment: прочитай пожалуйста http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Поставить обратный слэш перед ней \'

Comment: ну какая же это "верхняя запятая". Это обычный апострОф (да, в русском ударение на последнее о).

Comment: а все понял спасибо за помощь))

Comment: Какбы, всегда все должно быть наоборот:) Русский не работать, а инглишь работать:)

Comment: @Ksovrela, откройте для себя работу с плейсхолдерами и навсегда забудьте об апострофах и прочем геморрое.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно экранировать либо весь запрос, либо входящий аргумент. Самое первое что приходит на ум это [addslashes](http://www.php.su/addslashes()). Так же есть встроенные mysql(i) функции вроде [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)